# In Selenium how to select from dropdown Multi-select value | iframe

Tags: selenium-webdriver, iframe, frame

How is possible to select a value "Multi-select" from div select block?
I know that's I need to start with frame, here I select frame, but its no works

Image with code
https://failiem.lv/u/y87xgphpu9

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.switch_to.frame('mainFrame')
select_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "OpertypeSelect")
select = Select(select_element)
select.select_by_visible_text("Multi-select")
```

But when I run a code I get error

```
 File "c:\Dev\powerem\powerem.py", line 72, in <module>
    select_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "OpertypeSelect")
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="OpertypeSelect"]"}
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.switch_to.frame('mainFrame')
select_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "OpertypeSelect")
select = Select(select_element)
select.select_by_visible_text("Multi-select")
```